# Multiple $http requests in Angular controller cross origin to REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

I am trying to do multiple GET-requests to my own REST API written in Java using Spring. 3/10 times both request will be handled fine. 7/10 one of the http-requests will fail with a 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource' error. I have a REST Controller like this:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonRestController {

@Autowired
ActivityTracker tracker;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
    tracker.addPerson(person);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Collection<Person> getPersons(){    
    return tracker.getPersons();
}  

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Person getPerson(@PathVariable long id){
    return tracker.getPerson(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/activities", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Collection<RunActivity> getActivitiesByPerson(@PathVariable("id") long id){
    return tracker.getActivities(tracker.getPerson(id));

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void updatePerson(@RequestBody Person person){
    tracker.updatePerson(person);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deletePerson(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    tracker.deletePerson(tracker.getPerson(id));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/fastest", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Person getFastestRunner(){
    return tracker.getFastestRunner();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/longest", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Person getLongestRunner(){
    return tracker.getLongestRunner();
}


}
```

My Angular application looks like this:

```
angular.module('trackerApp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.router', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        TITLE: 'Welcome!',
        INTROMESSAGE: 'Use this Activity Tracker application for free!',
        en: 'English',
        nl: 'Nederlands'
    })
    .translations('nl', {
        TITLE: 'Welkom!',
        INTROMESSAGE: 'Gebruik deze volledig gratis activiteitstracker!',
        en: 'English',
        nl: 'Nederlands'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

    $stateProvider
        .state('persondetails', {
            url: '/runners/:userId',
            templateUrl: 'views/activitiesByPerson.html',
            controller: 'personDetailController as personDetails'
        });
})

.controller('personDetailController', function($http, $stateParams){
    var personDetails = this;
    var userId = $stateParams.userId;

    var reqUrlTwo = 'http://193.191.187.14:10578/RestTracker-1.0-SNAPSHOT/person/' + userId;

    $http({
        url:  reqUrlTwo,
        method: 'GET'
    }).success(function(response){
        personDetails.person = response;
    });

    var reqUrl = 'http://193.191.187.14:10578/RestTracker-1.0-SNAPSHOT/person/' + userId + '/activities';

    $http({
        url: reqUrl,
        method: 'GET'


    }).success(function(response){
        personDetails.activities = response;
    });


});
```

So 3/10 times both GET-request will be handled fine and results will be shown. But 7/10 times one of the 2 will fail and show me

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://193.191.187.14:10578/RestTracker-1.0-SNAPSHOT/person/2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

How is it that sometimes both will succeed and sometimes just one won't?

I have also tried using @ResponseBody and setting the headers and XML setup

Comment: I think `The response had HTTP status code 500` is the lead here. Does your API on server handles CORS?

Answer (score 0):

Check request headers, `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin` must be send from server. See http://enable-cors.org

Comment: `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin` is sent by the server, not client.